# PhP Cake app in Apache2 in Ubunutu not working but working find in window's wamp

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cakephp, lamp

I have a web application that is writen in php using cake framework. In windows environment i use wamp and it works find if i enbale apache read_write. Then I shift to use Linux environment Ubuntu 15. I have installed apache2 already and php too. it is all work. But when I put my app in /var/www in ubuntu and open the web page it said that the require_once function cannot file the location of the file.

I already change the owner of the www/* to www-data already, but it is still not work. mod_readwrite of apache is also enabled. So I want to know how could I enable read_write in Lamp like in wamp that I did on window? I met the same error in window if I don't enable it. So think it is the problem. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you will want to check for is that you're using the proper directory separator in any paths you're using for your require statements (this can be done by using the [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant in place of hard coded slashes in your paths)

Another thing you will want to do is look at the apache configuration for each environment and ensure that they are the same. In particular check to ensure that your virtual hosts are defined correctly.